# ionic 2 http.post forbidden 403 error on android device

Tags: ionic2, xmlhttprequest

I make http.post on api and take me error forbidden 403

this code not give me error test on browser but if i try to android device give me error

How can i solve this problem.

Thanx to now

```
kanallistele()
{

  var veri;

     this.kanallardiv=true;
    this.uyegirisdiv=false;
    this.kanallistelebtn = false;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );  
    //headers.append('Authorization' , 'Basic '+ btoa(tok));
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let postParams = {
    token: "381f13d7056-ce5fe474919",
    user_id: "71",
    }

    var veris="channel_name_";
    this.http.post("https://iothook.com/api/v1.0/channels/", postParams, options)
      .subscribe(data => {
        veri = data['_body'];
        console.log(veri);       
        veri= veri.slice(1, -1);
        veri = veri.replace(/\\/g, "");
        veri = JSON.parse(veri);
        for(var i = 0 ;;i++)
          {
              if(!veri.channel_list['channel_name_' + (i)])
                    break;   

              this.veriler.push({channelname: veri.channel_list['channel_name_' + (i)],channelid: veri.channel_list['channel_id_' + (i)]});              
          }
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);// Error getting the data
      });  
  }
```

Comment: have you checked on `postman` ? working on `postman` or not?

Comment: worked on postman

Comment: worked on postman. if I try to on browser with allow-control-allow-origin:* plugin working. but I try to android device not working

Comment: In device you face `allow-control-allow-origin:` error?

Comment: yes I think. but when I add  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');  but I take same error

Comment: For `allow-control-allow-origin` error  at server side you have to set response header like `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, `access_toke`, `authorization`, `content-type`..

Comment: we solved origin problem but 403 forbidden error continue

Comment: According to this site : http://www.codingandclimbing.co.uk/blog/ionic-2-post-json-cross-origin-cors-403-forbidden-hate-your , CORS must be enabled on your web server / backend. Also, in your code, you need to add Authorization in your http header